# Pushing Dockerfile or docker-compose to heroku

Tags: heroku, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I built a web app using docker and tested it locally by building a docker-compose file. Now I want to push the project to heroku. Do I need to make a Dockerfile and push the image to heroku or can I push the docker-compose file to heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to push Dockerfile. Docker-compose the only way to exec multiple container.

Comment: Have you an example of the command in the Procfile which calls docker compose?

Comment: More info please!